# Clone from bitbucket private repository using jenkins Pipeline as code

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

im using jenikins pipeline as code to clone a git project which is in private bitbucket repository(stash repository). i used this code block to clone the project in my pipeline script.

```
node {  
//checkout from master  
stage 'checkout'  
   withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'MyID', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {  

      git url: 'https://paulrda@devMyCompany.org/stash/scm/test_automation.git' , branch: 'development'   
   }  
}
```

'MyID' is the credential ID and my username and password is correct.i save my credentials in global credentials feature in jenkins. but i get this error when i build the jenkins task.

```
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://paulrda@devMyCompany.org/stash/scm/test_automation.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:803)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1063)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:109)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:73)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://paulrda@devMyCompany.org/stash/scm/test_automation.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://paulrda@devMyCompany.org/stash/scm/test_automation.git/'

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1745)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:801)
```

In my mac machine under my paulrda account i can successfully clone my project using jenkins pipeline script but when i change to another account and run jenkins i get this error. still i cant understand why i get this error. please provide a solution to this problem.

my configurations.
Jenkins version : 2.19.2
Credentials Plugin : 2.1.8
Git plugin : 3.0.0
Git client plugin : 2.1.0

Comment: Below error message says `Authentication failed for 'https://ralles@dev.zaizi.org`, which is a different user name than your code above (by intention?). But check username and password. You could also use `sh "echo $GIT_PASSWORD"` within the `withCredentials` step to verify.

Comment: So reading the whole error message probably not only helps you to resolve your problem, but also to apply anonymization ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It's failing to authenticate because you are not passing the credentials to the `git` call correctly.

Since you are using the Git plugin and not a shell command, there's really no need to use `withCredentials` at all. You can pass the `credentialsId` directly to `git` call, like that:

```
stage('checkout') {
    git credentialsId: 'MyID', url: 'https://devMyCompany.org/stash/scm/test_automation.git', branch: 'development'
}
```